# Sort multidimensional map based on pair value

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, boost, vector

I have a map defined as follows:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>> groupList;
```

**GOAL:**
I have a list of groups of commands. I want to sequence through each group in order. In order to do this, each group has a "sequence" value. I want to sort the overall list based on this value from smallest to largest. Essentially, I have a list of elements, which each have an accompanying list of other values within them specific to each parent. I want to sort the list of parents by a specific pair or value within the child lists.

For me to visualize this, I created an array in PHP with a similar structure. I'm not sure exactly how to visualize a C++ map so this is just me making assumptions. 1, 2, 3 are the keys of the map.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [groupID] => 1
            [sequence] => 0
            [command] => DefaultState
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [groupID] => 2
            [sequence] => 2
            [command] => Restart
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [groupID] => 3
            [sequence] => 1
            [command] => Beep
        )

)
```

I'd like to sort this map based on the value of a particular pair inside, in this case "sequence". Element "2" should be below element "3" when sorting using the "sequence" value. **The end result would look like this:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [groupID] => 1
            [sequence] => 0
            [command] => DefaultState
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [groupID] => 3
            [sequence] => 1
            [command] => Beep
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [groupID] => 2
            [sequence] => 2
            [command] => Restart
        )

)
```

I'm sorry to mix languages here but there's no simple way for me to dump a map that depicts its structure (that I know of).
At first, my map was set up like so:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> groupList;
```

This was easier for me to add elements and then access them later, but I figured a vector pair would be easier to use for sorting. I would prefer to use the latter definition for ease. I was looking at using `std::sort` and `boost` but I've had no luck implementing for this specific case.

Any comments/help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: it is a bit confusing... maybe it would be more clear if you would tell what you actually want to map to some data structure. Your `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>>` smells like overkill.

Comment: Consider a C++ map an ordered collection of distinct keys related to objects. That ordering is established by the map declaration itself. It isn't "sorted" later. It would help *immensely* if you described what it is you're trying to do rather than exclusively how you're trying to do it.

Comment: I've edited to show the end result better and added an explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish. I don't think the order of map can be changed so I might need to implement it differently.

Comment: I would suggest you to create an own `struct` or `class` for such a complex structure. If it is _indeed_ a `map` or a `vector` of something, then use the `std::` version, but if you use a `pair` just to avoid creating own type, then better create it. Then everything will be clearer.

Comment: Is it really that complex of a structure? It seems that this would be something a lot of people have implemented, or something similar.

Comment: @KevinMurphy, it might be not that complex, but adding field names that speak for themself (explain what is what) really helps. Now it is not really easy to understand what do you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Petr I've added the desired result in array form as to show you what I currently have and what I'd like it to look like after sorting. I've also explained it as best as I can in text.

Comment: What are the keys of your map? If they are `1`, `2`, `3` as you showed, this is called a vector or array, not map.

Comment: @AntonSavin yes 1, 2, 3 are the keys. What makes them not a map - just the fact that they're integers? I've defined them as strings as the keys are being pulled from an XML document.

Comment: @KevinMurphy so when you are populating the map, make values of `sequence` the keys.

Comment: @AntonSavin I could do that but I don't know what that would do to the design in the future. Is it not possible to sort the list using a child value as I stated above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31126961/85371), and in case you're really looking for something more advanced, here's what comes to mind using Boost MultiIndex containers:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cca340403eb5697c)</kbd>**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Item {
    int groupID;
    int sequence;
    std::string command;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Item const& i) {
        return os << "Item { group:" << i.groupID << ", sequence:" << i.sequence << ", command:'" << i.command << "' }";
    }
};

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
using Table = bmi::multi_index_container<
        Item,
        bmi::indexed_by<
            bmi::ordered_unique<
                bmi::tag<struct by_group>,
                bmi::member<Item, int, &Item::groupID>
            >,
            bmi::ordered_unique<
                bmi::tag<struct by_sequence>,
                bmi::member<Item, int, &Item::sequence>
            >
        >
    >;

#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

int main() {
    Table arr = {
        { 1, 0, "DefaultState" },
        { 2, 2, "Restart"      },
        { 3, 1, "Beep"         },
    };

    for (auto& item : arr.get<by_group>())
        std::cout << item << '\n';

    std::cout << "\nsorted by sequence:\n";
    for (auto& item : arr.get<by_sequence>())
        std::cout << item << '\n';
}
```

Prints

```
Item { group:1, sequence:0, command:'DefaultState' }
Item { group:2, sequence:2, command:'Restart' }
Item { group:3, sequence:1, command:'Beep' }

sorted by sequence:
Item { group:1, sequence:0, command:'DefaultState' }
Item { group:3, sequence:1, command:'Beep' }
Item { group:2, sequence:2, command:'Restart' }
```

Comment: Thanks! As an example, how would I access the "command" element for the item with the groupID of 2? When using a map, I can just use the [] operator and find data easily. Like `Item["2"]["command"]`.

Comment: Well. You can't really have your cake and eat it too. But you can "hack" it, e.g. using PropertyMaps: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c42852828be43f33)**. For the simple Item type here the compiler could optimize the cost away. Note the semantics are different though: an element will optionally be inserted, but the return is not by reference.

Comment: I'd personally make an accessor function that hides the mechanics from you here, instead of forcing the thing to look like a mutable `std::map`

Comment: I think you're probably right. C++ is new to me and the structure is a lot different. How would you recommend going about creating an accessor function? Something similar to that coliru link you posted? I guess I need something to delete an element by group ID, add a new element, etc. Hmm..

Comment: Wow okay perfect, thanks so much! The one thing confusing me is this is of the Table class, right? So while we're calling it `arr`, it's technically not an array. So adding after initialized or deleting then shifting would be completely different process than an array or vector, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82003/discussion-between-kevin-murphy-and-sehe).

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I see a datastructure, I imagine to have a definition for it handy:

```
struct Item {
    int groupID;
    int sequence;
    std::string command;
}
```

Now you can trivially define the array:

```
Item arr[] = {
    { 1, 0, "DefaultState" },
    { 2, 2, "Restart"      },
    { 3, 1, "Beep"         },
};
```

Since it's a simple aggregate with value semantics, you can just define an order and sort it:

```
struct Item {
    int groupID;
    int sequence;
    std::string command;

    bool operator<(Item const& other) const {
         return sequence < other.sequence;
    }
};
```

### Demo

Adding a streaming operator<< and we get a full working demo:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca0a2eebfe8d80c7)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>

struct Item {
    int groupID;
    int sequence;
    std::string command;

    bool operator<(Item const& other) const {
        return sequence < other.sequence;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Item const& i) {
        return os << "Item { group:" << i.groupID << ", sequence:" << i.sequence << ", command:'" << i.command << "' }";
    }
};

#include <algorithm>
int main() {
    Item arr[] = {
        { 1, 0, "DefaultState" },
        { 2, 2, "Restart"      },
        { 3, 1, "Beep"         },
    };

    std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));

    for (auto& item : arr)
        std::cout << item << '\n';
}
```

Prints

```
Item { group:1, sequence:0, command:'DefaultState' }
Item { group:3, sequence:1, command:'Beep' }
Item { group:2, sequence:2, command:'Restart' }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. However, I do want to be able to access the data using the groupID which is why in my question, I have a map with the parent element having the group ID as a key. I'd like to keep a similar structure.

Comment: See the other answer then. Basically it comes down to this: maps are ordered containers. You cannot have the elements in two orders at the same time (logical contradiction). So you need separate collections. Databases have been using multiple indexes for this since Rome was founded